# How to use PyODConverter with OpenOffice 4.1 (Mac)

Tags: python, macos, openoffice.org

I want to use openoffice to convert docx documents to pdf. I am planning to use PyODConverter for that. I am told that for the converter to work, i need to call the python that comes with OpenOffice. 
Here's the link /opt/openoffice.org3/program/python

I am on Mac and I have OPenoffice installed on /Applications. I am looking at the following folders
/Applications/OpenOffice.app/Contents/MacOs and /Applications/OpenOffice.app/Contents/program

I don't see python anywhere. I don't know where to find it.

Has anyone used PyOdconverter with openoffice4? Can anyone tell me how to use this?

Answer (score 0):

So, the answer to my own question is that OpenOffice installation on mac doesn't come with python (As far as I have dug).

As to how to use PyOdConverter with OpenOffice? You use LIbreOffice instead of open office. Installing LIbreOffice on mac, will give you python bundled with the software.

One thing to remember is that, latest version of libre office comes with python3. But the script [PyOdConverter.py][1]

[1]: https://github.com/mirkonasato/pyodconverter is written for python 2. So, you will have to make some updates on the script before you use it.